# MySQL Join VIEW, Concatenate Columns into ONE STRING

Tags: mysql, view, phpmyadmin

I created a VIEW from tables that works just fine. The problem is that in my tables I have "FIRSTNAME" and "LASTNAME" as separate columns. In my view I want to Concatenate them together  as a full name.

MySQL:

```
CREATE VIEW leader_table AS
SELECT 

 lgl_leaders.LEAD_ID,
 lgl_type.LG_TYPE,
 member_db.FIRSTNAME AS PRIMARY_FNAME,
 member_db.LASTNAME AS PRIMARY_LNAME,
 lgl_leaders.LG_ADDRESS,
 lgl_leaders.LG_CITY,
 lgl_leaders.LG_ZIP,
 lgl_leaders.LG_LAT,
 lgl_leaders.LG_LNG,
 lgl_leaders.CHILDCARE,
 lgl_leaders.LG_DAY,
 lgl_leaders.LG_TIME

 FROM
   lgl_leaders,lgl_type,member_db
 WHERE
       lgl_type.IDNUM = lgl_leaders.LG_TYPE
 AND   member_db.IDNUM = lgl_leaders.PRIMARY_LEADER
```

An example would be:

member_db.FIRSTNAME:  "BOB"
member_db.LASTNAME: "SMITH"

I would like one cell - called "FULLNAME" to read:  "BOB SMITH" instead of having separate columns.

How would I modify my view to join the two strings together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CONCAT()`

```
CREATE VIEW leader_table AS
SELECT 

 lgl_leaders.LEAD_ID,
 lgl_type.LG_TYPE,
 CONCAT(member_db.FIRSTNAME ," ",member_db.LASTNAME ) FULL_NAME,
 lgl_leaders.LG_ADDRESS,
 lgl_leaders.LG_CITY,
 lgl_leaders.LG_ZIP,
 lgl_leaders.LG_LAT,
 lgl_leaders.LG_LNG,
 lgl_leaders.CHILDCARE,
 lgl_leaders.LG_DAY,
 lgl_leaders.LG_TIME

 FROM
   lgl_leaders,lgl_type,member_db
 WHERE
       lgl_type.IDNUM = lgl_leaders.LG_TYPE
 AND   member_db.IDNUM = lgl_leaders.PRIMARY_LEADER
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks alot! I'll accept as answer once the time limit lets me. Thanks again!

Comment: If one ore more of the columns you are concatenating is nullable, then you should use `COALESCE()` to replace the NULL values with empty string to avoid a NULL `FULL_NAME` if one of `LASTNAME` and `FIRSTNAME` is NULL.